# Interface property model not validating

Tags: c#, .net, validation, asp.net-web-api, interface

I have a class which has various child objects:

```
public class ApplicationPayload
{
    public Quote Quote { get; set; }    
    public IApplication Application { get; set; }
    public DeliveryPreferences DeliveryPreferences { get; set; }
}
```

I have an api controller method which accepts this model:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LtdCompanyPost([FromBody] ApplicationPayload payload)
{
}
```

When submitting to the controller method, properties within classes that implement IApplication are not being validated (validation seems to be being ignored), however, the other objects (Quote / DeliveryPreferences) are being validated as expected.

Is it possible to have my objects implementing IApplication validatable, or is this structure simply not going to work for me?

(I tested the objects implementing IApplication by having them at the same level as Quote/DeliveryPreferences, having removed the interface implementation, and the validation worked as expected, so the validation rules themselves are not the issue).

Any advice? I can give more examples if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are falling foul of the below check in the `ComplexModelBinder`, an interface has no constructor.

But more broadly, how would it know what implementation of the interface to instantiate?

```
 if (modelTypeInfo.IsAbstract || modelTypeInfo.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) == null)
 {
    var metadata = bindingContext.ModelMetadata;
    switch (metadata.MetadataKind)
    {
        case ModelMetadataKind.Parameter:
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                Resources.FormatComplexTypeModelBinder_NoParameterlessConstructor_ForParameter(
                    modelTypeInfo.FullName,
                    metadata.ParameterName));
        case ModelMetadataKind.Property:
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                Resources.FormatComplexTypeModelBinder_NoParameterlessConstructor_ForProperty(
                    modelTypeInfo.FullName,
                    metadata.PropertyName,
                    bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ContainerType.FullName));
        case ModelMetadataKind.Type:
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                Resources.FormatComplexTypeModelBinder_NoParameterlessConstructor_ForType(
                    modelTypeInfo.FullName));
    }
}
```

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/24eaa740f5b1736700d8d91053f60d690f4fc17e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs#L366,

Comment: Hi @Bryan, agreed, this sounds like what is happening.. As for ho it would know, I guess it would not. I confess, this is not my code, I picked it up once we spotted validation was no longer working after some refactoring. I guess there's no easy way around this other than casting/mapping to a type and then calling validation again? Excuse any ignorance here.. I am jumping in at the deep end with this project lol

Comment: I suggest replacing the interface in your model with a concrete type instead. If there is only one implementation of the interface, they answer is easy, if there are more, you will have to choose one.